# Using git submodule causing npm package size too big when publish

Tags: node.js, git-submodules

`git submodule add` will add the whole project as submodule including all their stuff, tests, etc.. which will in turn causing the publish package size too big.

Is there any way to overcome this?

Comment: You should probably use npm `dependencies` instead of submodules.

Comment: I need to use a c++ project. so i add it as submodule

Answer (score 1):

You can add a [`.npmignore` file](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/developers#keeping-files-out-of-your-package) with a list of glob patterns (like `.gitignore`) for files to exclude from the publish.

Comment: Huh? This only affects `npm` operations (publish, pack, etc)

Comment: I'm not sure the effect of this so just making sure. Shall give it a try and feedback later. Thanks